# How to adjust header and admin-bar on Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, html

I am trying to design a wordpress theme that has a problem with admin bar. If I select "don't show user bar" it's working properly. But when I want to see admin bar in the top, the themes looks like picture I attached. I couldn't see my logo its accurate size.

[image]

Comment: You wanna hide the admin bar?

Comment: can u send me link demo or code?

Comment: No. I want to give a space between admin bar and logo which is also compatible with tablets and phones.

Comment: @Logeshwaran I couldn't decide which code I should've sent. Which code or page you need?

Comment: @Mehmet where is ur logo in the above pic?

Comment: You see an orange image with W and H value it's my logo. Now its not its accurate size because of the admin bar. We couldn't see rest of the logo. @Logeshwaran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could customize the admin bar layout by making it almost transparent in order to see what lies beneath it. This can be accomplished by overriding the default admin bar style used by WordPress so to make it 30% opacity and fully visible only on hover:

```
function my_theme_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'admin-bar', array( 'callback' => 'my_admin_bar_style') );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_setup' );

function my_admin_bar_style() {
?>
<style>
    #wpadminbar {position:fixed;opacity:0.3;}
    #wpadminbar:hover {opacity:1;}
</style>
<?php
}
```